# javascript display different error message

Tags: php, javascript

I have two page (page1.php and page2.php) that need to put the javascript coding.
On the page1.php, there have two images link to page2.php.

This is the code for page1.php:

```
<a href="page2.php"><img src="btn1.png" id="img1"></a>
<a href="page2.php"><img src="btn2.png" id="img2"></a>
```

This is code for page2.php:

```
<input id="t_c" type="checkbox" name="t_c" value="1"/>
<input type="image" value="continue" src="images/btn_cont.png"/>
```

If user click image1, it will go to page2.php. then if user didn't click the checkbox, there will display the error message.

If user click image2, it will go to page2.php. then if user didn't click the checkbox, there will display different error message.

Comment: @Leeyaginger are you familiar with event registration?

Comment: i tried use the if else but its not working..im not sure whether the condition is wrong or page2.php dont get the image id.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte nope..since im new in javascript..

Comment: Do you need any coding on page 1? Seems to me you only need to add script to the continue button

Comment: @Leeyaginger [Read this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener), and take special notice of the example. It clearly lays out how to register a simple click event to a DOM element, such as a link. Since you're new to JavaScript, you may want to spend some time reviewing the introductory concepts, such as events.

Comment: on page1.php, user just need to select the image. how to script the continue button? im a little bit stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input type image is a submit button.

If page 2 is a php page, the best solution is - as mentioned by jeff9888 to select the message to show on the server. If you must use JavaScript, pass the parm in the query string, it will show in location.search on pages 2

Page 1

```
<a href="page2.php?parm=img1"><img src="btn1.png" id="img1"></a>
<a href="page2.php?parm=img2"><img src="btn2.png" id="img2"></a>
```

Page2:

```
<hmtl>
<head>
<title>Page 2</title>
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    if (!this.elements["t_c"].checked) { // note the "this" keyword
      if (location.search.indexOf("img1")!=-1) { // ?id=img1
        alert("Please check the checkbox for image 1");
      }
      else  {
        alert("Please check the checkbox for image 2");
      }
      return false; // cancel submit
    }
    return true; // allow submit
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
  <input id="t_c" type="checkbox" name="t_c" value="1"/>
  <input type="image" value="continue" src="images/btn_cont.png"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks..but if user click image2, it need to display different error message.

Comment: i have tried it..but it display "Please check the checkbox for image 2" when i clicked both image.

Comment: Did you add the parameter to the call? "page2.php?parm=img2"><

Comment: ooo...i mislook at it...yeah..its working... :)

Comment: Great - Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Send get variable to your page2.php:

```
<a href="page2.php?id=img1"><img src="btn1.png" id="img1"></a>
<a href="page2.php?id=img2"><img src="btn2.png" id="img2"></a>
```

then in your page2.php, use the ID you get to decide what error message you want to display.

```
<?php
if($_GET['id']=='img1')
    $msg="Message 1";
else if($_GET['id']=='img2')
    $msg="Message 2";
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) but i need to do it using javascript..

Comment: Okay, I think you can set cookie when the image is clicked, after that get cookie from your page2.php to define which error message to display.

Comment: @jeff9888 Or `localStorage` to store information.